# Swap color/RGB values in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, rgb

I am trying to swap color values - R to G and G to R in my illustration (well, a selection on it). In the end, a (200,100,0) would be (100,200,0).
I found various pages that does color swapping and inversion but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Could anyone help me with that or lead me to an answer if it already exists?

Thanks!

Comment: I think some scripting would be required to do this

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @JohnB
I found a script on another page and modified it a bit. In case anyone else needs it (or wants to improve it), this seems to work for me:
`var fillRGBColor = function (pathItems){
    for (var i=0; i < pathItems.length; i++) {
        r = pathItems[i].fillColor.red;
        g = pathItems[i].fillColor.green;
        pathItems[i].fillColor.red = g;
        pathItems[i].fillColor.green = r;
    }
}

fillRGBColor(app.activeDocument.pathItems);
`
sorry, couldn't manage to get it in a code block

Comment: @meono If the script you posted in your comment works and answers the question, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JohnB's suggestion, I solved the issue with a simple script. I found a template function on another page and modified it a bit. In case anyone else needs it (or wants to improve it), this seems to work for me:

```
var fillRGBColor = function (pathItems){
    for (var i=0; i < pathItems.length; i++) {
        r = pathItems[i].fillColor.red;
        g = pathItems[i].fillColor.green;
        pathItems[i].fillColor.red = g;
        pathItems[i].fillColor.green = r;
    }
}

fillRGBColor(app.activeDocument.pathItems);
```

Comment: You could have linked your reference by the way.

Comment: function is based on this example:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8672780/4010982

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired the **Recolor Artwork** command?

Select the object(s) that you want to recolor.  In this case, I'll change the color of the orange lights on my truck.

[image: truck]

With your object(s) selected, go to **Edit > Edit Colors > Recolor Artwork**

[image: menu]

Then you can select which colors you wish to change and edit their values.  In this case, I want to change the orange lights (200,100,0) to the green you gave (100,200,0).  Next to the orange bar, you will see a rectangle split in half (circled in blue).  Double-click that rectangle and the color picker dialog box pops up, like in my example below.

[image: options]

When you've swapped your colors, click Ok.

[image: truck2]

Comment: Yes but if there are 150 colors?

Comment: Yes, my issue was too many colors (basically a red-yellow-green spectrum). I think I solved the issue with a script - which I'll comment above in a sec

Comment: I thought he was only swapping the values on one color